# Azure Logic App: Permissions to Run Trigger

Tags: azure, logicapp, stopstartvmv2

Is there a role/right which we can assign to a logic app which would allow a user to click its `Run Trigger` button; but nothing more.

### Context

We recently implemented [Start Stop V2](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/start-stop-vms/overview) on our VMs to reduce costs of our legacy apps by having them shutdown outside of standard usage hours.

Sometimes our users need to work weekends or evenings though.  Rather than having them rely on us to bring the systems up in such ad-hoc scenarios, we'd like to allow them to run the `ststv2_vms_Sequenced_start` logic app to bring the system back online (in such cases we won't stop the system again, as potentially other users may log in after the initial person - we'll just leave the system online after a custom start and take the cost hit, as this scenario should be fairly infrequent).

We'd like to assign users an option to manually click the `Run Trigger` button to start the system; whilst minimizing their rights in Azure (ideally so they only have access to trigger the function, and nothing else).